# How can I view how many messages I have sent in the Microsoft Outlook web interface?

Tags: outlook.com

How can I view how many messages I have sent in the Microsoft Outlook web interface?

I haven't found anything interesting in the Microsoft Help.

Comment: I've been looking for the answer to this myself, and I haven't had much luck either.  I think Franck's okay here.